# Create long types in JPA entities

Tags: jpa, eclipse-plugin, entity

I'm trying to generate JPA entities from tables using eclipse plugins, I defined some BIG INT and Date columns. I would like to have long type in Entity class for those BIGINT columns, But It generates as String. Please help me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds really weird that the Eclipse plugin generates those columns as String - check that you haven't missed / misread something.

If the column really is a BIG INTEGER in the database, just changing the type of the property field to Long should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you mean long properties, but try to use @Type annotation. Example:
**@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.LongType")**

Comment: I just updated my question. It long type. I would like to have either long or Long in generated Entity classes and I don't want to specify the type in annotations.